# xamarin.android device debug is not showing vs13

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin for my Android App development and it is Trial version.
I can debug Xamarin.Android App in Emulator but I want to run my App in Android Device. Device option is not available in Debug menu.

Please help me out...........

Comment: If you type in CMD adb -devices, can you see your device?

Comment: Have you enabled the debbuging on your android device? Have a look here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/

Comment: Yes I have enabled Debugging on my Device.